# Can Arrays. sort sort enumerations that have been added to a an array.?

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have an enum with the Ranks of a Deck.  I add these Ranks into an array. When I used Arrays.sort to sort the array using a custom comparator it didn't sort instead it returned this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:291)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:171)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at HW3.Deck.sort(Deck.java:69)
    at HW3.War.main(War.java:100)
Java Result: 1
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Bellow is the code:

```
@Override
`   public int compareTo(PlayingCard o) {
    if (this==o) return 0;
    if(this.getSuit()!=o.getSuit()){
        return this.suit.compareTo(o.getSuit());
    }

     else {
         return this.rank.compareTo(o.getRank());
     }   
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sounds like there was a null element in the array?

Comment: Enums are sortable as they implement the Comparable interface. The use the ordinal to sort. If you're getting a NullPointerException, you probably have a null in the array. Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), you'll have to take care of *null* values yourself.

**Example**

```
Arrays.sort(enums, new Comparator<Rank>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Rank o1, Rank o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Put NULL to the end.
        if (o1 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        return o1.compareTo(o2); // sort by ordinal
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. it seems i compared it the wrong way when I implemented CompareTo wrongly.

Comment: @NickSpirit: If it helped, you could click the checkmark besides an answer to mark this question as solved.

Comment: Hey one last thing if you don't mind. Why does it the compiler give me a null exception error?

Comment: @NickSpirit: `o.getSuit()` will fail, if `o` is null.